# How can I create a new variable and change its data type?

Tags: r

I need to create a new variable from by subtracting datetimes from two separate columns.  I then need to change this column into a numeric vector.

When I mutate to create the variable (diff) it stays in time in seconds.  I divided these seconds by how many seconds there are in a day to get total days.  (although its in the form 1.065e+01 secs).

I need this is variable (diff) to be in Days without adding another new variable.  I used as.numeric but it doesn't convert to the format I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
data <- mutate(odata, diff = (time1 - time2)/86400)
```

```
mutate(odata, diff = difftime(time, time2, units = "days"))
```

This worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: `mutate(odata, diff = difftime(time, time2, units = "days"))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference between two times in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019126/time-difference-between-two-times-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

r2evans suggested:

```
mutate(odata, diff = difftime(time, time2, units = "days"))
```

Was able to use this.